# How to include translations in custom install profile

Tags: drush, i18n-l10n, installation-profiles

I'm creating a custom install profile and want to be able to use drush make to quickly set up all files.

What is the best way to have drush make download the drupal core translation files into my install profile?

Drush make does exactly that (by copying all core translations into the profile's translations dir), but only for the 3 default install profiles.

The code doing that (drush/commands/make.project.php:462) includes the following comment:

```
        // If this is the core project type, download the translation file
        // and place it in every profile and an additional copy in
        // modules/system/translations where it can be detected for import
        // by other non-default install profiles.
```

Ok, this would make sense *if* I knew how to detect those translations and make drupal aware of them to be able to use them in the setup.

Any ideas what a working approach would look like?
Thanks a lot!